# Dynamic model of a two-mass mechanical system taking into account the Gear Ratio

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia, angular-velocity

> Two-mass rotational system has the following form and is represented in following structural diagram.
> [image: 1]
> $\tau_e$, $\omega_1$ and $J_m$ are the motor torque, angular velocity and moment of inertia respectively.
>
> $\tau_s$, $\tau_s$, $\omega_2$ and $J_d$ are the shaft torque, load torque, angular velocity and load moment of inertia respectively
>
> $K_{md}$ is the shaft stiffness

**Problem:** how to include a gear ratio $N=\omega_1/\omega_2$ in equation of motion and in in a block diagram respectively?

Here is the Lagrangian for the entire system:
$$L=T-V=J_m \frac{\omega_1^2}{2}+J_d \frac{\omega_2^2}{2}-\frac{K_{md}(\phi_1-\phi_2)^2}{2}$$
And I don’t understand how to insert the gear ratio here?

**EDIT:**
As an additional material, here is a dual mass gearbox system.

[image: 2]

Comment: you don’t have gear ratio, because in your model there isn’t gear box  between the two shafts

Comment: @Eli yes it is, but I assume it is. Those. the sequence is as follows: motor - gearbox - shaft with stiffness factors - load.

Comment: @Eli see my edit, let assume, that gearbox include in system

Comment: you can use this equation $\omega _{out}=i\,\omega _{in}$ where i is the transmission ratio

Comment: @Eli Yes I know. I do not know how to turn the gear ratio into Lagrangian and get the equations of motion taking into account the gear ratio.

Comment: write the kinetic energy input and output and put this constraint equation for the angular velocity

Comment: @Eli https://ibb.co/820MQKY 
but then we get two Lagrangians, that strange

Comment: @Eli could you kindly form your advice in the form of an answer to this question, I think this will help not only me

Comment: o.k I will do it for you later

Comment: @Eli I will be very grateful to you, as soon as you are ready - let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Kinetic Energy
\begin{align*}
&T=\frac{1}{2}\left(J_{1in}\dot\varphi_{1in}^2+
J_{1out}\dot\varphi_{1out}^2+
J_{\varphi'_1}\dot{\varphi'}_1^2+
J_{\varphi'_2}\dot{\varphi'}_2^2+
J_{2}\dot\varphi_{2out}^2\right)
\end{align*}
Potential Enegry
\begin{align*}
 &U=\frac{c_1}{2}\left(\varphi'_1-\varphi_{1out}\right)^2+
 T_1\,\varphi_{1in}+ T_2\,\varphi_{2out}+T_{d1}\left(\varphi'_1-\varphi_{1out}\right)
\end{align*}
constraint equations
\begin{align*}
&\dot\varphi_{1out}=i_1\,\dot\varphi_{1in}\\
&\dot\varphi'_2=\frac{r_1}{r_2}\,\dot\varphi'_1\\
&\dot\varphi_2=i_2\,\dot\varphi'_2
\end{align*}

with $\mathcal L=T-U$ and the non holonomic constraint equations you can obtain the equations of motion. substitute the damper torque $T_{d1}=-d_1\left(\dot\varphi'_1-\dot\varphi_{1out}\right)$ into the EOM's

alternative substitute the constraint equations into the kinetic and potential energy and obtain the EOM's